# Scanf is messing up my char arrays?

Tags: c, arrays, scanf

I have the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
  int i=0;
  char x[]="q";
  char b[]="f";

  printf("Enter a letter:");
  scanf(" %s", x);

  while(i<5)
  {
    printf("%c\n", x[i]);
    i++;
  }

  i=0;

  while(i<5)
  {
    printf("%c\n", b[i]);
    i++;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

> Can someone explain why the `char` array `b` is not printing out?

I just get a little white box. The same thing happens in another program I have where the `scanf` reads the input into BOTH arrays (`x` and `b`). i.e If I type 'x' into the input both the arrays become x!

> Can some help me understand why this is happening and help me find a solution to this very aggravating problem.

Comment: Please learn how to use a debugger, to be able to at least try to help your self in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Both the `x` and `b` arrays are arrays of only *two* elements, and (for example) the `x` array is initialized to `'q'` and `'\0'`. If you input anything more than a single character for `scanf` to read, you will write out of bounds of the array `x`, leading to *undefined behavior*.

You also access the arrays out of bounds when printing, once again leading to *undefined behavior*. The `b` array you *start* indexing at index `5`.